# Solr multilanguage synonyms

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a website with multiple languages and synonyms. Synonyms are defined in a txt file like "xxx, yyy, zzz".

Now in one language xxx and yyy mean the same thing but in another language they mean totally different things. So in the other language I get a mix of results.

How to tell solr that this "xxx, yyy, zzz" relationship exists only for products with language value of "1" and "xxx, www, qqq" relationship exists for products with value "2"?

This could of course be done, when I would but the products to different servers. But maybe there are alternative methods?

At the moment we use solr 3.5 but we want to change that in the future anyway, so if it can't be done on 3.5 can it be done it later versions?

Answer (score 0):

You could have one field (or set of fields) per language (product_name_en, product_name_fr, product_name_es...), define one field type per language, and define one specific SynonymFilterFactory, with a different synonym file, for each field type. Then the query generation takes the language into account to choose which fields to query against.

Comment: Business side is lagging with decision to let me investigate. :)